# Question on Application of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

Suppose that g is a function that is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. Show that:

1) There exists $a_1<a_2$ in $(0,1)$ such that $g'(a_1)+g'(a_2)=2$

2) There exists $a_1<a_2$ in $(0,1)$ such that $\frac{1}{g'(a_1)}+ \frac{1}{g'(a_2)}=2$

3) There exists $a_1<a_2$ in $(0,1)$ such that $g'(a_1)g'(a_2)=1$

I know by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $a$ such that $f'(a)=1$, but I am not sure on how am I supposed to show the existence of two items satisfying the conditions.

Many thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in(0,1)$ and $b=f(a)$. By the Mean Value Theorem there exist $a_1\in(0,a)$ and $a_2\in(a,1)$ such that:
$$
g'(a_1)={b\over a}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
g'(a_2)={1-b\over 1-a}.
$$
Now it is only a matter of finding $a$ such that the given conditions are verified:

1) let $a=1/2$;

2) let $a$ be a solution of the equation $g(x)=1/2$, so that $b=1/2$;

3) let $a$ be a solution of the equation $g(x)=1-x$, so that $b=1-a$.

It is easy to prove that equations in 2) and 3) have at least one real solution in $(0,1)$.

Comment: $2)$, $3)$ have at least one real solution in $(0,1)$ by Intermediate value theorem. For $3)$ you can use it for $h(x)=g(x)+x$, where $h(1)=2$, $h(0)=0$ and $h(x)$ is continuous when $x\in [0,1]$ and $h(x)=1$ has a real solution in $x\in(0,1)$.